# Помогите разобраться с лагом в верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

http://websterjoy.tk/sites/viewport/

Если в браузере IE выбрать режим документов IE8 или 7, то вы увидите как съезжает блок. Но если в правом верхнем углу у надписи "Subscribe by RSS ..." убрать float:right, то все станет нормально. Почему так? как решить этот глюк?

Comment: Условный комментарий с условием для осла 8 и ниже, где убираете float:right;

P.S. А в IE5.5 всё нормально? ))

Comment: Но я же не могу убрать, мне нужно чтоб к правому краю прижималось,а с позиционированием тоже глюки... Неужели нету способа это пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы мне кажеться не закрыли спан

```
`<span class="rss-and-email">Subscribe by <a href="#">RSS</a> or <a href="#">Email</a> for updates!</a>`
```

на 54 строке. То есть если все остальные браузеры нормально воспринимают, то старые просто не закрывают спан сами, вот и происходит ошибка. 
Думаеться мне надо было бы так сделать

```
 `<span class="rss-and-email">Subscribe by <a href="#">RSS</a> or <a href="#">Email</a> for updates!</a></span>`
```

Comment: Один </a> - лишний

Comment: Блииин, точно! спасибо!